# Middle-aligning (center) borders of different widths

Tags: html, css

How can I middle/center align borders of differing widths?

**HTML**

```html
<div>
  <span class="large">This is </span><span class="small">a test!</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.large {
  border-bottom: 5px solid blue;
}
.small {
  border-bottom: 1px solid green
}
```

See here:
https://jsfiddle.net/ybgeL9rf/

I would like the 1px border to be aligned to the middle of the 5px border (instead of the top).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a padding-bottom of 2px to `.small`:

```
.large {
    border-bottom: 5px solid blue;
}
.small {
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid green
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ybgeL9rf/1/)

Comment: Great and simple solution!

Comment: @Aegix, well simplicity is oft the key to an answer. People over-think to much.